# How to use onKeyDown method in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, keylistener, keyevent

I've two Fragments. both of them have a list of some audio files. when and audio is playing a seekBar will pop up, and when media is finished sekkBar will slide down and hide.

Now I've decided for a better view if a user wants to hide the seekBar during playing the media, show_and_hide the seekBar with hardware MENU_KEY in both Fragments separately.

I'm doing it like this but it is not working:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.light_fragment_main, container, false);

        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                boolean check = true;

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

                    if (check){
                        toast("slide DOWN");
                        check = false;
                      }

                else {
                        toast("slide UP");
                        check = true;
                }


            }


                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: onKeyDown is Deprecated in android, i suggest you to use callback class with onBckPressed() method of your Fragment activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using view Pager with tab Fragments, so I've implemented onKeyDown method in my Fragment's MainActivity, and control the visibility of my seekBar from there. This is how I'm doing it:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {

        if (ZZZLightFavorites.isPlaying) {
            ZZZLightFavorites z = (ZZZLightFavorites) ZZZLightFavorites.favFragment;
            z.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ZZZLightFavorites.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            if (z != null) {
                if (ZZZLightFavorites.seekBarVisibility) {
                    z.slideDownSeekbar();
                }else {
                    z.slideUpseekBar();
                }
            }
        }

        else if(ZZZLight.isPlaying) {
            ZZZLight z = (ZZZLight) ZZZLight.mainFragment;
            z.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ZZZLight.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            if (z != null) {
                if (ZZZLight.seekBarVisibility) {
                    z.slideDownSeekbar();
                }else {
                    z.slideUpseekBar();
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```